# How to show dragging animation when drawing boxes on canvas in Java?

Tags: java, canvas, drawing, mouseevent, vaadin

I have a canvas and am using mouse event listeners to draw boxes. However, the boxes will only appear on mouseUp, but what I want is for the boxes to be shown as they are drawn so that the user can see the size of the box they are drawing.

This is my code for mouseDown and mouseUp:

```
public Canvas(int width, int height) {

element = getElement();

element.addEventListener("mousedown", event -> {  // Retrieve Starting Position on MouseDown

            Element boundingBoxResult = ElementFactory.createDiv();
            element.appendChild(boundingBoxResult);

            JsonObject evtData = event.getEventData();

            double xBox = evtData.getNumber("event.x");
            double yBox = evtData.getNumber("event.y");
            boundingBoxResult.setAttribute("data-x", String.format("%f", xBox));
            boundingBoxResult.setAttribute("data-y", String.format("%f", yBox));

            BoundingBox newBox = new BoundingBox(0, xBox, yBox, 0.0, 0.0);
            arrayBoxes.add(newBox);

            isDrawing = true;

            mouseIsDown=true;


        }).addEventData("event.x").addEventData("event.y");


        element.addEventListener("mouseup", event -> {  // Draw Box on MouseUp

            Element boundingBoxResult2 = ElementFactory.createDiv();
            element.appendChild(boundingBoxResult2);

            JsonObject evtData2 = event.getEventData();

            endX = evtData2.getNumber("event.x");
            endY = evtData2.getNumber("event.y");
            boundingBoxResult2.setAttribute("end-x", String.format("%f", endX));
            boundingBoxResult2.setAttribute("end-y", String.format("%f", endY));

            double xcoordi = 0;
            double ycoordi = 0;
            double boxWidth = 0;
            double boxHeight = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayBoxes.size(); i++) {
                arrayBoxes.get(i).setName(i + 1);
                arrayBoxes.get(i).setWidth(endX, arrayBoxes.get(i).xcoordi);
                arrayBoxes.get(i).setHeight(endY, arrayBoxes.get(i).ycoordi);
                xcoordi = arrayBoxes.get(i).getXcoordi();
                ycoordi = arrayBoxes.get(i).getYcoordi();
                boxWidth = arrayBoxes.get(i).getWidth();
                boxHeight = arrayBoxes.get(i).getHeight();

            }

                mouseIsDown=false;
                context.beginPath();
                context.setFillStyle("limegreen");
                context.setLineWidth(2);
                context.strokeRect(xcoordi, ycoordi, boxWidth, boxHeight);
                context.fill();

            System.out.println(arrayBoxes.toString());

        }).addEventData("event.x").addEventData("event.y");

}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **mousemove**-eventlistener *in* the mousedown event, and remove that listener again in the mouseup event. This is done so that there is not always a mousemove eventlistener active when it's not needed.

In the mousemove eventlistener, draw the outline of a rectangle with the x1/y1 from the mousedown position and x2/y2 of the current mouseposition. Always remove/reuse the rectangle-outline from last mousemove event so there is always only one such rectangle-outline present.

<sub>I don't know how to make a rectangle outline in canvas, but seeing how you have been working with that for a while (see your other questions :D) I assume you know how to do that.</sub>